# how to set python module path to jupyter notebook

Tags: path, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to use object_detection API in google cloud notebook. I followed installation instruction. It appears that I have no problem to import api in python3.

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import object_detection
>>> from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
2019-09-12 08:53:29.964341: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
```

However, I was not able to do same thing in jupyter notebook.

Ok. According to what I can find on_line. I tried following things: (1) cd $home (2)nano .bashrc (3) add one line:

```
export JUPYTER_PATH="/home/jupyter/Tensorflow/models/research/":$JUPYTER_PATH
```

It turns out this didn't work neither. I am not sure if there is anything I did wrong.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@derec after you have added the required line, type this command: `source .bashrc`.
This executes the **.bashrc** file and then close the terminal window.

Whenever you edit **.bashrc** file, always put the above mentioned command after editing it.

Comment: It doesn't help at this time. I solved the problem by "import sys; sys.append("path") for each module.

Comment: @derec You mean sys.path.append("path") actually.